# Browser does not render appended child node

Tags: appendchild

I'm experimenting with web service to transmit new elements to document DOM.

So I'm preparing a XML on server side with necessary informations to do that job. My server side XML is as followed:

```html
<Root>
<Command>Add
<Data><button id="PB" style="width:600px; height:100px;"/></Data>
</Command>
</Root>
```

This XML will be caught by following page.
You will see XML has a command id "Add", which should add the nodes below data to the page.

When code is running, the button will be created and shown properly in document DOM (see code function onMessage), but it will not be rendered. 
The browser debugger tells me, the width and height of the button seems to be Null. When I edit the attributes in browser debugger, the button will be rendered after change. I get this behaviour on Chrome and IE.

I need a hint, what has to be changed to let it run.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8002/chat"; 
var output;
var websocket;

"use strict";

function init() { 
    output = document.getElementById("output"); 
    testWebSocket(); 
} 

function testWebSocket() { 
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; 
    websocket.onopen = function (evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) }; 
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) }; 
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) }; 
} 

function onOpen(evt) { 
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED"); 
}

function onClose(evt) { 
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED"); 
} 

function onMessage(evt) { 
    var parser, xmlDoc, NodeCommand, but;

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(evt.data, "text/xml");

    NodeCommand = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Command");

    switch (NodeCommand[0].textContent) {
        case "Add":
            output.appendChild(NodeCommand[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0]);
            break;
    }
} 

function onError(evt) { 
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data); 
} 

function doSend(message) { 
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
    websocket.send(message); 
} 

function writeToScreen(message) { 
    var pre = document.createElement("p"); 
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word"; 
    pre.innerHTML = message; 
    output.appendChild(pre); 
} 

window.addEventListener("load", init, false); 

</script> 

<html>

<head>
<title>WebSocket Test</title> 
</head>

<body>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2> 

<div id="output"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

This can't be done in this (intuitive) way. Elements have to be created over document.